# How to use Strut tags inside JavaScript functions?

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts-1

I'm trying to retrieve values with struts tags inside JavaScript function, because it's being called a lot of times, and I won't go each line making respective changes when needed. I want to make it once.

I have this working in the same JSP:

```
function myNewWindow(file_type, file_name){
    Window= window.open('MyClassAction_ac.do?metodo=Start&docType='+file_type+'&docName='+file_name,'_blank','width=810,menubar=no,toolbar=no,scrollable=yes,resizable=no');
}
```

....

```
<a href="javascript:myNewWindow('<bean:write name="MyClass" property="type"/>','<bean:write name="MyClass" property="name"/>');">
    <img src="<%=path%>img/img1.jpg" width="14" height="14" hspace="0">
</a>
```

But I need something like this:

```
function myNewWindow(){
   var file_Type= <%= <bean:write name="MyClass" property="type"/> %>
   var file_name = <%= <bean:write name="MyClass" property="name"/> %>
   Window= window.open('MyClassAction_ac.do?metodo=Start&docType='+file_type+'&docName='+file_name,'_blank','width=810,menubar=no,toolbar=no,scrollable=yes,resizable=no');
}
```

Comment: To work your script should be in the jsp page not in separate js file. `var file_Type=  '<bean:write name="MyClass" property="type"/>'`

Comment: It's in the same JSP I'm working on.

Comment: Check your JS logs and the rendered source; it's unlikely that throwing random variable properties into JS will work without both quoting the JS value and JS-escaping what you're rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work :

```
var file_Type= '<bean:write name="instanceofMyClass" property="type"/>'
```

So you need to have instance of myclass in one of the scopes: request, session or application

Comment: what exception ?

Comment: Cannot find MyClass in any scope. But  MyClass is being used in many places. I'm not sure if the exception references that or something else.

Comment: you should add MyClass to the imports on the page or use full classname with packages. For example:  com.sample.MyClass

Comment: Do you have bean:write tag in the imports?

Comment: Yes, as <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean"%>

Comment: I don't know how it work behind, but It is used all over the JSP and there are not instances of MyClass. Maybe <bean:write> have an implicit request